# Error when I try to run an app in android Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I have this error when I try to run my app in android

An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Ionic\MyProject\www\32-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Ionic\MyProject\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js")
See "C:\Users\UserN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-GJZvQx\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

Comment: Please I need an Answer right now

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in [this workaround](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680#issuecomment-601896916)

1. delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. add "resolutions": { "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7" } to package.json
3. npm install npm-force-resolutions --save-dev
4. npm install
5. npx npm-force-resolutions
6. npm install again
7. run or build your app

if the error persist in future builds of your app try from step 5 before build it.

Answer (score 1):

open package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0"
}
```

run command 
`npm install`
and then build your project and it should work.